# How to interact with pynessus

Tags: python

I am using http://code.google.com/p/pynessus/ so that I can interact with nessus using python but I run into problems trying to connect to the server. I am not sure what I need to set pynessus too?

I try connecting to the server using the following syntax as directed by the documentation on the site but I receive the following error:

n = pynessus.NessusServer(localhost, 8834, root, password123)

Error:
root@bt:~/Desktop# ./nessus.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./nessus.py", line 634, in 
    n = pynessus.NessusServer(localhost, 8834, root, password123)
NameError: name 'pynessus' is not defined

Comment: The problem is that Python doesn't find the `pynessus` module. Did you install it?

Comment: If I downloaded the source from http://code.google.com/p/pynessus/ shouldn't I just be able to add onto the pynessus.py file I am adding my own code in the file I downloaded. They don't import pynessus and I am not sure how to install it since it doesn't say how to install it in the documentation

Comment: Just place the `pynessus.py` in some folder. Then create a new file in the same folder and `import pynessus` from it. Also, you should *really* learn the basics of Python programming before using such a library (as you most probably need to dig in its source to find out how it works or how you need to use it).

Comment: Ah, thank you very much I am trying to learn more. I have not come across this yet and was very confused. So I guess when something is a module I should be able to import it.

Comment: Yes, and every single Python tutorial mentions this. You could start with [the official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/). Also if this helped you, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't import the `pynessus` module. To solve this problem, simply place the downloaded `pynessus.py` in the same folder as your Python script and add the line

```
import pynessus
```

at the top of that script. You can reference the `pynessus` library in your script only after that line.